# Arrylist not display properly in android using arrays

Tags: android, arraylist

I have this type of date that comes from web, i have these data listed all in after parsing on array list

```
ArrayList<String> countriesid= new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> countriesName = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> cityid= new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> cityName= new ArrayList<String>();
```

Here is the my actual data, in xml format,

```
<Info>
<countryId><![CDATA[1]]></countryId>
<countryName><![CDATA[USA]]></countryName>
<cityId><![CDATA[1]]></cityId>
<cityName><![CDATA[New York]]></cityName>
</Info>
<Info>
<countryId><![CDATA[2]]></countryId>
<countryName><![CDATA[Japan]]></countryName>
<cityId><![CDATA[5]]></cityId>
<cityName><![CDATA[Tokiyo]]></cityName>
</Info>
<Info>
<countryId><![CDATA[6]]></countryId>
<countryName><![CDATA[USA]]></countryName>
<cityId><![CDATA[5]]></cityId>
<cityName><![CDATA[Los Angeles]]></cityName>
</Info>
<Info>
<countryId><![CDATA[19]]></countryId>
<countryName><![CDATA[USA]]></countryName>
<cityId><![CDATA[15]]></cityId>
<cityName><![CDATA[San Diego]]></cityName>
</Info>
<Info>
<countryId><![CDATA[3]]></countryId>
<countryName><![CDATA[Spain]]></countryName>
<cityId><![CDATA[4]]></cityId>
<cityName><![CDATA[Barcelona]]></cityName>
</Data>
```

**Note: edited**
and i have already  model class like this:

```
 public class FullInfo{

      public String countryName;
      public String cityName;
      public int countryId;
      public int cityId;
}
```

At, First step, I have done removing all the repeated(duplicate) countries name in list:
and display like this picture:
**What I have Done:**

For Removing duplicate Name

```
ArrayList<String> RemoveSameCountry= new ArrayList<String>();// fro temp arraylist



 Set set = new HashSet();
    List newList = new ArrayList();
    for (Iterator iter = countriesName.iterator(); 
    iter.hasNext();) {
    Object element = iter.next();
    if (set.add(element))
    newList.add(element);
    }
    RemoveSameCountry.clear();
    RemoveSameCountry.addAll(newList);
```

***It works fine***

[image]

After display on list, I have to click USA, then I have to display Cities on list:
Like this:

```
 If i click USA, How to display list of Cities of USA, I have not idea.
```

[image]

Finally, want to display details of the one city, when click one. If i click new york , then display like this:
[image]

**My Code: http://pastie.org/pastes/8026498/text**

Answer (score 2):

Create a Info class

```
public class CityInfo {

  public String countryName;
  public String cityName;
  public int countryId;
  public int cityId;
}
```

and keep an `HashMap<String, List<CityInfo>>`

String (the key of the `HashMap`) can be the `countryName`. Your first `ListView` can be filled with the `keySet` of the `HashMap`.

Suppose that City ListView has dataset of String object. When you click on a row, the onListItemClick is fired: There you can retrieve the

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
     MyAdapter myAdapter = (MyAdapter)l.getAdapter();
     String key = myAdapter.getItem(position);
     List<City> cities = hashMapInstance.get(key);
}
```

Comment: Please add more info, how to display city of country USA, when click USA on list item countries, I have no idea. how to use hashmap on class.

Comment: Please see my code: i have not implemented your: http://pastie.org/pastes/8026498/text